# Dropdowns Not Working on Website After Code Upload to InfinityFree Hosting

Tags: web, hosting, web-hosting, development-environment, visual-web-developer

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am encountering an issue with my website hosted on InfinityFree. I have successfully uploaded my code via cPanel, and the webpage functions properly on my local system. However, when accessing the site online, certain dropdowns are not opening as expected.

I suspect this might be a hosting-related problem. I have attached screenshots for reference:

1. [Dropdowns Working Locally](https://pasteboard.co/BXeEfGklTkdy.png)
2. [Dropdowns Not Opening on Website](https://pasteboard.co/2idI0gTA9jy0.png)

[And I'M USING DOMAIN NAME OF GODADDY]

I've already contacted InfinityFree support, providing my credentials. Unfortunately, I haven't received a resolution yet.

If anyone has experienced a similar issue or has expertise in web hosting, your insights would be greatly appreciated. Please help me understand why the dropdowns are not functioning on the live site despite working locally.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Best regards,

Harrshit

I've asked godaddy about this but they said you need to contact to your hosting service platform.